# "android.view.View is deprecated" - what else to use or how to fix?

Tags: android, view, deprecated

I have just started trying out Android Studio, following the instructions on a video tutorial.

Here is my take on what the guy tells me but I keep getting the error message View is deprecated.

[image]

How do I fix this? Or what do I use instead?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button sendButton0001 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend0001);
    EditText welcomeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWelcome);
    sendButton0001.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the message?

Comment: Here is a screenshot [link](https://imgur.com/a/xmyozZx)

Comment: [View does not deprecate by google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). It just warning, clean build and rebuild again.

Comment: Really, really strange. Keep on using the View.OnClickListener, the View class does not seem to be deprecated. At least that's what the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) says. Maybe your Android Studio settings for Lint are somehow damaged?

Comment: @immodi how exactly do i do that?

Comment: You can try with Build menu -> clean build and Rebuild option or File menu -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart

Comment: Nope. Still error. It DOES work and i am succesfully ignoring it, but its still weird

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning. I don't know why it shows up, but if it runs fine - don't take care.