# how to fix 'strikethrough view' in android studio

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In android studio after typing `onClickListner` it shows ~View~ instead of simple View.

In picture you can see what I'm doing:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: don't post pictures of code. post the actual code

Comment: The line usually indicates a class is deprecated - are you using Android Studio

Comment: The strikethrough is just the IDE's way to let you know that the View object is deprecated. With respect to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008555/android-view-view-is-deprecated-what-else-to-use-or-how-to-fix) SO question, you need not worry.